# What would be a good equation to smoothly connect these two line segments? ($y=1$ and $y=c^{-x}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I am trying to build a smoothed decay envelope.

If I have a signal starting a $y=1$, and want it to transition to $y=c^{-x}$, what would be simple/effective for doing this mathematically in the space between?

For example:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/frsrrd0ad3

This is for smoothing the decays of audio signals, so in principle, there should be no sharp edges or discontinuities. It should be the simplest, most natural, smooth line for which there are no obvious points or corners.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want it to behave in between?

Comment: In a purely mathematical sense I'm not absolutely sure, which is partly why I'm asking. This is for smoothing the decays of audio signals, so in principle, there should be no sharp edges or discontinuities. It should be the simplest, most natural, smooth line for which there are no obvious points or corners. I'll add that to my question to clarify. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I meant, is there something you are trying to optimise? Minimal arclength, Minimal computation-time, etc, or any solution subject to your conditions will do?

Comment: If all you need is a $C^1$ transition, you can use a cubic spline: just adjust a cubic polynomial to take the values you need at both ends and have the corresponding values of the derivatives (4 conditions on 4 coefficients of the cubic).

Comment: Here's a link to your Desmos file with the cubic spline added 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b2si40b5zj

Comment: That is absolutely perfect @WW1! Looks like cubic spline is exactly what I want. Could I ask just one more thing? Would it be possible to rephrase that in terms of two variables, say "d" and "f", where "d" represents the x-value at which point the interpolation begins (on y=1) and "f" represents the x-value at which point the interpolation meets y =c^-x? This might be rudimentary for you but it would save me hours of studying cubic interpolation to try to figure out myself. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I know what you are asking for, but I'm a bit confused by the $(x-1)$ in the exponent of your function in Desmos. could the exponential  function be written ...
$$  y=c^{f-d-x}  \{ x \ge f \} $$
or should it be just
$$  y=c^{-x}  \{ x \ge f \} $$